How to log details of SSJS 400 error
I'm writing a script that will delete contacts found in a data extension from the parent and child BU and then delete the record in that DE. After repeatedly getting a 400 error without understanding why, I discovered that one of my deletion requests actually had worked, and the 400 error was happening because the DE of records to delete was empty. Is there any way that I can log the reason for the 400 error instead of just the generic "bad request"?
 <script runat="server">

    Platform.Load("core","1");
    var DE = "Deletion DE Key";
    var logDE = "Log DE Key";
    var log = DataExtension.Init(logDE);
   
    try {
     
        var url = 'https://xxxxxx.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token';
        var contentType = 'application/json';
        var payload = {
            "grant_type":"client_credentials",
            "client_id":"xxxxxx",
            "client_secret":"xxxxxx"
        };
        var authRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
        var statusCode = authRequest["StatusCode"];
        var response = authRequest["Response"][0];
        var accessToken = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response).access_token;

        var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload), headerNames, headerValues);
        result = Stringify(result).replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');

        url = "https://xxxxxx-4.rest.marketingcloudapis.com";
        url += "/contacts/v1/contacts/actions/delete?type=listReference";
        var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
        var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];

        payload = {
             "deleteOperationType": "ContactAndAttributes",
             "targetList": {
               "listType": {
                 "listTypeID": 3
               },
               "listKey": DE 
             },
           "deleteListWhenCompleted": false,
           "deleteListContentsWhenCompleted": true
        };
    
        result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload), headerNames, headerValues);
        result = Stringify(result).replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
        log.Rows.Add({"Message": "result: " + result});

    } catch (e) {
        e = Stringify(e).replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
        log.Rows.Add({"Message": "error: " + e});
    }
</script>


There are more advantages to using the Script.Util.HttpRequest method than Http.POST. For example, in this case, you can get the response when the response status is 400 Bad Request.
Here is a sample response for this so it is easier to visualize:
{
    "targetListInformation": {
        "listName": {
            "value": "DE name"
        },
        ....},
     .....,
    "hasErrors": true,
    "resultMessages": [
        {
            "resultType": "Validation",
            "resultClass": "Warning",
            "resultCode": "DeleteList.CanClear",
            "message": "This data extension will be cleared."
        },
        {
            "resultType": "Validation",
            "resultClass": "Error",
            "resultCode": "SendableDataExtensions.IsEmpty",
            "message": "The referenced data extension does not contain any rows."
        }
    ],
    ...
}

Based on the response. It seems good enough to have them in the log DE.
E.g. My log DE has 3 fields: DEname (text), hasErrors (Boolean), message (text).
I would try something like this:
 <script runat="server">

    Platform.Load("core","1");
    var DE = "Deletion DE Key";
    var logDE = "Log DE Key";
    var log = DataExtension.Init(logDE);

    // Get access token     
    var url = 'https://Your_Sub_Domain.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token';
    var contentType = 'application/json';
    var payload = {
        "grant_type":"client_credentials",
        "client_id":"Your Client ID",
        "client_secret":"Your Client Secret"
    };
    var authRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
    var statusCode = authRequest["StatusCode"];
    var response = authRequest["Response"][0];
    var accessToken = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response).access_token;

    // Call API to delete contacts
    url = "https://Your_Sub_Domain.rest.marketingcloudapis.com";
    url += "/contacts/v1/contacts/actions/delete?type=listReference";

    payload = {
            "deleteOperationType": "ContactAndAttributes",
            "targetList": {
            "listType": {
                "listTypeID": 3
            },
            "listKey": DE 
            },
        "deleteListWhenCompleted": false,
        "deleteListContentsWhenCompleted": true
    };

    var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
    req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
    req.retries = 2;
    req.continueOnError = true;
    req.contentType = "application/json"; 
    req.method = "POST";
    var auth = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
    req.setHeader("Authorization", auth);
    req.postData = Stringify(payload); 
    var resp = req.send();

    var resultJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.content));

    //Define variables for DE log
    var DEname;
    var hasErrors;
    var message;

    var hasErrors = resultJSON.hasErrors;
    var resultMessages = resultJSON.resultMessages;
    
    var DEname = resultJSON.targetListInformation.listName.value;
    //Write(DEname + "<br>");
    //Write(hasErrors + "<br>");
    if (resultMessages.length> 0){
        for (var i=0; i < resultMessages.length; i ++){
            var resultClass = resultMessages[i].resultClass;
            if (resultClass == "Error"){
                var message = resultMessages[i].message;
                //Write(message);
            }
        }
    }
    // Add log to log DE
    log.Rows.Add({"DEname": DEname,"hasErrors": hasErrors, "message": message});

</script>

Result:



DEname
hasErrors
message




DE name
true
The referenced data extension does not contain any rows.




Thanks for responding! When I ran this code, I was getting a result that there were no errors, but the contacts in the data extension were not cleared and the request didn't start processing until I moved it to the shared data extensions folder. Any ideas about why it didn't throw an error?

@KK In order to perform the contact deletion, you need to ensure they are in the parent BU context. So your client credentials, Data Extension need to be from the parent BU. The shared DE folder is in parent BU context, so it will work if you move a DE from a child BU to the shared DE folder. Also, the DE needs to be a sendable DE.
